# Google App Engine Static Frontend Instance Does Not Start

Tags: google-app-engine

My static front-end instance (B1 instance_class) does not start when I make a URL request to it. Any idea? I had not touched my Google App Engine project for the past 4 weeks and suddenly it doesn't work any more.

When I try to access the url, I get 404 Not Found problem. No instance of the static front-end module starts.

If my dispatch.yaml is as follows, if I make the following call : www.jitai-api.appspot.com/jawbone_work, it should be routed to the static-frontend module, right? This doesn't seem to happen.

```
application: jitai-api

dispatch:
- url: "jitai-api.appspot.com/"
  module: default

- url: "jitai-api.appspot.com/jawbone_work*"
  module: static-frontend

- url: "jitai-api.appspot.com/google_work*"
  module: static-frontend
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs for your application?

Comment: No I don't. @JoshTriiJohnston

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston, no instance of the static module ever starts when I make a request. I just get the 404 Not found error.

Comment: Have you logged into the cloud console https://console.developers.google.com/project for your project and checked the logs, settings, application versions, and running instances to see if there are any issues? You could also try to re-deploy your app using `appcfg.py` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: how do you redeploy the static module using appcfg.py again? @JoshTriiJohnston

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/appcfg you will have to click the link for the language you use unless by *static module* you mean all static content in which case it would be: `appcfg.py -A update app.yaml`

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston, I figured out what the problem is. My dispatch.yaml doesn't seem to work. I have updated my question. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch rules match the hostname `jitai-api.appspot.com`, not `www.jitai-api.appspot.com`. Try defining them like this:

```
application: jitai-api

dispatch:
- url: "*/jawbone_work*"
  module: static-frontend

- url: "*/google_work*"
  module: static-frontend

- url: "*/"
  module: default
```

From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_with_a_dispatch_file)

```
# Matches the hostname 'customer1.myapp.com', but not '1.customer1.myapp.com. 
- url: "customer1.myapp.com/*"
  module: static-backend
```